# Chart series being truncated to 16,384 values after modifying the values

Tags: excel, vba, series, excel-charts

I'm using Excel 365

I have a chart that has XY scatter data -- potentially upwards of 20,000 values.

Outliers in the data are so far out of the norm that the range gets compressed and the chart becomes less meaningful. I want to clean up these outliers for visual purposes, but not alter the original data.

When I run the cleanup routine, I'm losing thousands of values. As an example, I have a series in the chart with about 20,100 XY data points. I'm trying to create a high pass filter to cut off anything that's more than three times the average -- so if a Y value is more than three times the average, I set it to three times the average.

My starting series values have a range of 1 to 39914 -- basically, I didn't think I'd need more than 40K entries.

I run through the data, clean up the "too high" values, and then alter the original series values ... and I end up with a range of 1 to 16384.

I seem to be hitting some sort of memory limit that doesn't apply to the initial array / collection / whatever, but does apply to the way I'm modifying things.

Here's the full code:

```
Sub ExportCharts()  ' Iterate through all charts and output to PNG files:
    Dim chartname As String
    Dim thevalues As Variant
    Dim objChrt As ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim seriescount, i, stopper As Long
    Dim highpass, thevalue As Double
    Dim s1 As Series
    Dim save1 As String
    
    chartname = "XYZ"
    
    Set objChrt = Sheets("1080p Med").ChartObjects("FrameTime_Chart")
    Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
    Set s1 = myChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    
    save1 = s1.Formula ' So I can restore the original formula for the chart
    
    i = 1
    stopper = 0
    highpass = (Worksheets("1080p Med").Range("C111").Value) * 3 'this is the high pass filter value
    thevalues = s1.Values
    Do Until stopper <> 0 Or i > UBound(thevalues)
        If IsEmpty(thevalues(i)) Then
            stopper = 1
        Else
            If i > 40000 Then 'ignore more than 40,000 items for now
                stopper = 1
            Else
                If thevalues(i) > highpass Then
                    thevalues(i) = highpass
                End If
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    s1.Values = thevalues
   ' thevalues here has a range of 1 to 39914 and s1 also has a range of 1 to 39914.
   ' After the above line executes, s1 has a range of 1 to 16384. What's going on!?
    
    myChart.Refresh 'Not sure this is working -- I want the chart to redraw with the new data

    Call ExportChart(myChart, chartname & "_3_FrameTime") 'Write out a PNG file of the chart.
    
    s1.Formula = save1  ' Restore the original data to the chart
End Sub
```

It would be easier to just modify the s1.Values array in place, but that's not allowed -- or I'm doing it wrong. Which might be part of the same root cause.

Comment: Does `s1.Values` have an empty cell at `i=16384`?